# How do i select a max of a sum with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with a problem.
I am trying to get a max from a sum with three tables. I've been trying to figure it out with help from other post on here but so far none of them have helped me. I manage to get the right answer when using limit 1 but i was wondering how I can do it without that.

The three tables are

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1anpI.png)

So far I got this

```
(select vnamn, sum(mangd) as a from land, export, varldsdel where varldsdel.vkod=land.vkod and land.landkod=export.landkod and ar=2004 group by vnamn)
```

this give me the following result

```
+----------------+-------------+
|     vnamn      | sum(mangd)  |
+----------------+-------------+
| sydamerika     |       61000 |
| noramerika     |       50000 |
| europa         |       1200  |
+----------------+-------------+
```

Now this is where I get stuck. I want to do a max of this result so that only "sydamerika | 61000" shows and I've been trying to do this all day but can't get the hang of it.

Thanks

Comment: What's the reason behind avoiding the `LIMIT` clause if I can ask? @Loldorre

Comment: This is part of a couple of practise questions to prepare you for an exam and sometimes they ask you to solve a problem without using limit. Therefore i want to be prepared if that would be the case and I don't want to "cheat" and just say something like mangd>60000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`Common Table Expression`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) (CTE) and then filter out on the highest value using the `MAX` aggregation function:

```
WITH summed_mangd AS (
    SELECT vnamn, 
           SUM(mangd) AS total 
    FROM       land
    INNER JOIN export
            ON export.landkod = land.landkod
    INNER JOIN varldsdel 
            ON varldsdel.vkod = land.vkod 
    WHERE ar = 2004 
    GROUP BY vnamn
)
SELECT vnamn,
       total
FROM summed_mangd
WHERE total = (SELECT MAX(total) 
               FROM summed_mangd)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. It gives me same answer as earlier. The one with all three rows. Thank you though

Comment: My bad, now you should get what you want. @Loldorre

Comment: It worked! thank you so much for helping me with this. I'm not familiar with the first statement, don't think they talked about this in my lectures. I'll have to take some time and study this but again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

since you already have the select query, you can do this instead;

```
Select vnamn, max(a) as mangd from (select vnamn, sum(mangd) as a from land, export, varldsdel where varldsdel.vkod=land.vkod and land.landkod=export.landkod and ar=2004 group by vnamn) k
```

Comment: I tried this exakt same code earlier as I was looking through other posts on here and unfortunately it returns an error, stating that it is missing a group by. If i put the group by in, I get the same result as before. Thank you though :)

Comment: @Loldorre sorry. I forgot to ask your mysql version. this code example is for mysql version 5.7